# How can I create multiple cmake targets with one dependent on the output of the other?

Tags: cmake

I'm learning `cmake`, coming from a `make`/`makefile` background.

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── foo.cpp
│   └── foo.h
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── unit
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── unit_test.cpp

3 directories, 7 files
```

**Intention/goal:**

1. I want the content of the `./src/` directory to be compiled into `libfoo.a`, and I want `foo.h` and `libfoo.a` installed to `/tmp/foo/include/foo/` and `/tmp/foo/lib/`, respectively.
2. I want `unit_test.cpp` to `#include <foo/foo.h>` and link with `-lfoo`.

**Question:**
In my top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, I have `add_subdirectory` statements for both `src` and `test` directories. When I run `make install` (which uses the `cmake`-generated `Makefiles`), it looks like it's descending into the `test/` directory before the `install` statements from `src/CMakeLists.txt` have been executed.
**How can I achieve the stated goal?**
I think what I am looking for is a way to create another make target...so that I can run "make install" first, which installs the files at their respective destinations, then - as a separate step - run another make target, which compiles the unit test files and makes use of libfoo.a and foo.h at their installed locations.

**Problem:**
As-is (files below), when I run `make install`, compilation of `unit_test.cpp` fails because the file `foo/foo.h` isn't found because it hasn't been "installed" yet:

```
cd /home/user/projects/scratch/cmake/build/test/unit && /usr/bin/c++    -I/tmp/foo/include   -o CMakeFiles/unit_test.dir/unit_test.cpp.o -c /home/user/projects/scratch/cmake/test/unit/unit_test.cpp
/home/user/projects/scratch/cmake/test/unit/unit_test.cpp:1:21: fatal error: foo/foo.h: No such file or directory
 #include <foo/foo.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

**What I have tried:**
If I comment-out the `add_subdirectory( test )` in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, then `foo.h` and `libfoo.a` are installed in the desired locations per goal #1.

---

**The Files:**

Apologies - I know this is an awkward way to distribute my project content, but I'm not aware of any easier/better way to share this. I've tried, though, to keep file content minimal.

```
# <root>/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /tmp/foo/)
add_subdirectory(src)

add_subdirectory(test) # If I comment this out, then "make install" succeeds
```

```
# <root>/src/CMakeLists.txt
add_library( foo foo.cpp )
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES foo.h DESTINATION include/foo)
```

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo();

#endif
```

```
# <root>/test/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(unit)
```

```
# <root>/test/unit/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable( unit_test unit_test.cpp )
target_include_directories( unit_test PUBLIC /tmp/foo/include )
target_link_libraries( unit_test PUBLIC /tmp/foo/lib )
```

```
// unit_test.cpp
#include <foo/foo.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But.. what for installing it? Just create the dir `foo`, move `foo.h` into `foo/` dir and include the directory. Why would you specifically want to install it in some `/tmp/` directory? Why would you want to install it in `/tmp/`?

Comment: @KamilCuk - this is a simplified/contrived simplification of a bigger/more complex project. I have a requirement to use cmake to do the header + lib "installation". The `/tmp/` installation location is also just an example - in my actual project, that will be some official location. I'm trying to learn from example how to do this, that's why I'm using this small project with "dummy" destination folders, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install it. Just compile it as you want as it is and create unit tests as you want. Use `target_link_libraries` to link between cmake *targets*. With the following directory structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── foo
|       └── foo.cpp
|       └── foo.h
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── unit
        └── unit_test.cpp
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
include(CTest) # From memory, not sure
add_subdirectory(src)
if (BUILD_TESTING)
    add_subdirectory(unit)
endif()

# src/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(foo foo/foo.cpp foo/foo.h)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# unit/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(unit_test unit/unit_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(unit_test PUBLIC foo)
add_test(NAME unit_test COMMAND unit_test)
```

Then configure&build&unit-test with:

```
cd the_project
cmake -S. -B_build
cmake --build _build
( cd _build && ctest )
```

Then if you want to let users install `foo`, add the whole `install(` stuff to `src/CMakeLists.txt`. There's little need to install when unit testing - `cmake` will manage dependencies and linking by itself. Installing is only used when you really want to install the stuff - I do not see the need to install anything to unit_test (unless you want to test the installation itself).

Comment: This wasn't the angle I was expecting, but it works perfectly as needed - thank you. :)  

I am still curious, though: what if I _did_ want to test the installation itself?  

This answer seems to take advantage of the specific `src/foo/` directory structure, which lets me do `#include <foo/foo.h>` in my `unit_test.cpp`. Is that okay/normal? I'm just still a little bit curious: what if I wanted the unit test to `#include` files from their final "installed" locations?  

Just curious -- but your solution does seem to fit my needs; thank you.

Comment: `Is that okay/normal?` It's normal. If you want to test installation, I suggest to have two separate cmake projects that are completely separate. One is for building and isntalling `foo` only, the other project is for using it from specific location. Get to know `add_library(... IMPORTED)` for that, or just use cmake packages and use `find_package` natively (and easily) from cmake.

Comment: [I have actually a real example](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/-/blob/master/Makefile#L308) of unit testing that has a [separate CMakeLists](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/-/blob/master/test/cmake_proj_tests/cmake_example/CMakeLists.txt#L4) with `find_package` for unit testing the installation.

Comment: @StoneThrow Consider adding `install(EXPORT ...)` and to add cmake configuration files for easy importing. Node that you need to differentiate between build and install locations of headers, see the code snippet at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html (but probably with INTERFACE replaced with PUBLIC.